# like is not working in mySql sub query

Tags: mysql

I have used some sub query , its not working at all ,if i am giving hardcoded id its working .

```html
SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    inventory_set_variations isv
  WHERE
    isv.c_catid LIKE '%[{"id":"c1.catid"}]%' AND isv.company_id = 1
) AS 'count_total_no_of_variations',
`c1`.`catid` AS `catid`

FROM
   category c1
WHERE
  (
    `c1`.`catsid` <> 3 AND c1.company_id = '1'
  )
```

this is not working ,

below code is working as i gave hard coded data

```html
SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    inventory_set_variations isv
  WHERE
    isv.c_catid LIKE '%[{"id":"1000020"}]%' AND isv.company_id = 1
) AS 'count_total_no_of_variations',
`c1`.`catid` AS `catid`

FROM
   category c1
WHERE
  (
    `c1`.`catsid` <> 3 AND c1.company_id = '1'
  )
```

Comment: did you get any error? or just no result?

Comment: i am getting zero count for all the categories

Comment: here i need to count all the variations of a category  , in variation table data is present as  [{"id":"anyid"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` to form `like` condition

Change

```
LIKE '%[{"id":"c1.catid"}]%'
```

to

```
LIKE CONCAT('%[{"id":"',c1.catid,'"}]%')
```

Comment: its returning zero.

Comment: SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    inventory_set_variations isv
  WHERE
    isv.c_catid LIKE CONCAT('%[{"id":',c1.catid,'}]%') AND isv.company_id = 1
) AS 'count_total_no_of_variations',

Comment: You’ll need the quotes too

Comment: @sradha what do you mean by `for this to work we need concat right`?

Comment: i mean we need to concat all the things , then its working .
but in my previous code its not working , why ?

because i used this code in all the places , its working fine except in subquery .

Comment: @sradha in your previous code,`c1.catid` is just a string,the sql executor will not parse it since you wrap `"` to it,so it will be a pure string `"c1.catid"`